# boto2 get_key() returns None on known key

Tags: python, boto

Has anyone encountered an issue where iterating over a bucket with boto2:
`for key in bucket.list()` and returning a generator, and then trying to do `get_key(key.name)` -`key.name` are the keys i get from the generator- would sometimes (seemingly unpredictably) return `None` .

That seems strange, as I apparently am getting the existing keys via `bucket.list`. I try printing `key.name` on those that fail, and weirdly it seems to be the valid key. If I try retrieving by the same `key.name` at a later point with `get_key()`, I successfully get it back.

I wonder if its possible there is some delay on s3 from the moment you upload media, to then being able to retrieve with `get_key` ? (I know that just`list()`ing doesn't return a full representation of the objects so that's one theory- that maybe the full representation isn't immediately available. But its strange that it fails on some keys, which if I try later are retrievable)

Comment: In the web UI of S3 are you seeing the key?

Comment: @liorko Yes, I can see it. Its there. I can also do `get_key` on it now, and it will retrieve it. It won't be None like when i got the error right after uploading.